# Display CPT Category List as Shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, shortcode

I'm trying to output the current post categories for my 'portfolio' custom post type as a shortcode.

At the moment I have this snippet in the functions.php

```
    function shows_cats(){
    $page_id = get_queried_object_id();
    echo '<h6>Categories</h6>';
    echo get_the_category_list('','',$page_id);
   }
   add_shortcode('showscats','shows_cats');
```

I've tried a few different combinations to call the CPT but have had no luck. I realise that this snippet is just outputting standard WP categories but was wondering if anyone knew a way to edit this to display the CTP instead.

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
// Get the taxonomy's terms
$terms = get_terms(
    array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'your-taxonomy',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    )
);

// Check if any term exists
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ) {
    // Run a loop and print them all
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) ?>">
            <?php echo $term->name; ?>
        </a><?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.

I've had another look into this and got something that works as a shortcode but not perfectly. Added the following to my functions.php file and using [showscats] as my shortcode in WPBakery it outputs the current custom post type taxonomies as a list. My CPT taxonomies being "project-type".

The only issue is that it shows all categories that belong to the CPT and not the ones applied to the current post.

```
// First we create a function
    function shows_cats( $atts ) {

// Inside the function we extract custom taxonomy parameter of our shortcode
 
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'custom_taxonomy' => 'project-type',
    ), $atts ) );
 
// arguments for function wp_list_categories
    $args = array( 
    taxonomy => $custom_taxonomy,
    title_li => ''
    );
// We wrap it in unordered list 
    echo '<ul class="portfolio-cats">'; 
    echo wp_list_categories($args);
    echo '</ul>';
    }
// Add a shortcode that executes our function
    add_shortcode( 'showscats', 'shows_cats' );
```